# Prolog exercise with Lists

Tags: list, prolog, definition, backtracking

I would be grateful if someone help me with the underneath exercise

If I have the prolog predicate `**split_list(Limit,List,High,Low) (split_list/4)**`
which has an integer list **List**, and one integer **Limit**, "returns" to list 
**High** all the data of list List which are greater or equal to **Limit** and 
the list Low which data are less of **Limit**. For instance:
`?- split_list(2, [0, 2, 1, 3, 4], High, Low).
High = [2, 3, 4]
Low = [0, 1]`

i) Give the **backtracking definition** of the predicate with **less possible 
controls.**

ii)Define a predicate **split_list_alt/3** with the same declarative meaning of [i)] (non Recursion definition)
//annotation:use predicates collection solutions(non backtracking)For instance:
`?- split_list(0, [0, 2, 1, 3, 4], High, Low).
High = [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
Low = []
Yes`

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following list of predicates to achieve this.

```
split_list(_,[],[],[]):-
    !.

split_list(N,[LH|LT],[LH|AT],B):-
    LH>=N,!,
    split_list(N,LT,AT,B).

split_list(N,[LH|LT],A,[LH|BT]):-
    split_list(N,LT,A,BT).
```